# Is there a portable way to statically initialise a recursive mutex?

Tags: pthreads, posix, mutex, recursive-mutex

According to POSIX, I can statically initialise a mutex this way:

```
pthread_mutex_t m = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

However, what if I want the mutex to be recursive? Mutexes are non-recursive be default and there's no way to supply mutex attributes to the static initialisation.

Comment: Is that C or C++? Suggestions might differ depending on which language you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no portable way to do this. A workaround may be initialise the mutex dynamically when it is first used. To prevent race conditions while doing the initialisation another non-recursive statically initialised mutex can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP;
```

Comment: _NP suffix means non portable. It works for linux. Try with PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER as described here http://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/manual/pthread_mutex_init.html if you care for portability

Comment: PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER is not defined by POSIX. What operating systems it is supported in?